# Trying to make a sprite rotate about a point (LibGDX/Java)

Tags: java, rotation, libgdx, 2d, sprite

What the title says basically. I'm making a new object in my Game (the image on the far left: http://www.graphic-buffet.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/spikes-and-blades-banner1.jpg) and want to make it rotate 180 degrees about the top like a pendulum.

For some reason it just flickers really fast and I haven't been able to find a way to do this. Any ideas? The javadoc of the rotate method:

*Sets the sprite's rotation in degrees relative to the current rotation. Rotation is centered on the origin set in setOrigin(float, float)*

```
public class SwingingSpikes extends GameObject {
...
public SwingingSpikes(float xPos, float yPos) {
    swingingSpikesTexture = new Texture("spikePendulum.png");
    sprite = new Sprite(swingingSpikesTexture);
    // Set the origin of the sprite
    sprite.setOrigin(xPos + sprite.getWidth() / 2,
            yPos + sprite.getHeight() / 2);
}

public void update() {
    // Constantly rotate the sprite by 180 degrees
    sprite.rotate(180);
}
...
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call rotate(180) it immediately rotates it another 180 degrees. That's why it flickers really fast. The update method gets called every frame. If you want it to rotate more slowly add an Action on the actor - in this case a [RotateToAction](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/RotateToAction.html)